# Wordpress multisites with different text direction

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello WordPress Savvies,

In order for us to create our WP site we were advised to do a multisite for each language; which we managed to do, our languages are Arabic and English, and we have successfully added both to the site, our only issue is the Direction on the page and text so we tried adding this to the header of our theme minding that both style.css and rtl.css are in place:

```
    >
    <?php if(get_bloginfo('language')=='ar_AR'){?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/rtl.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    *{ direction: rtl; }
    </style>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen"> 
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    *{direction: ltr;}
    </style>
    <?php } ?>
```

Amongst other things and nothing is working for us! Thank you for your help and advice!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the `is_rtl()` function at all? http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_rtl

As per the Codex, this function "Checks if current locale is RTL (Right To Left script)."

Example code as follows:

`if ( is_rtl() ) {
  wp_enqueue_style(  'style-rtl',  plugins_url('/css/style-rtl.css', __FILE__) );
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script-rtl', plugins_url('/js/script-rtl.js',  __FILE__) );
}`

i.e. instead of adding this to the the header of your theme, this should be added to the **functions.php** file so that the correct CSS/JS files are enqueued.